# ssms: adding a username

Tags: sql-server

i would like to be able to access a database from a remote machine

should i be adding a username in this prompt? if so, where do i input the password? i do not see the dialogue where i can assign a password for a username? or maybe i can just use existing usernames? 
[alt text http://img293.imageshack.us/img293/1919/15159985.png](http://img293.imageshack.us/img293/1919/15159985.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object Explorer > Security > Logins:

[image]

That was present in 2005 as well.

Resources:

- [SQL Server 2005 Logins](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/sql-server-2005-logins)
- [Basic SQL Server Security concepts - logins, users, and principals](https://laursqlserver.blogspot.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Right click on Logins under security from the management console.  This will give you an option for a new login.

Comment: i dont  have LOGINS under security, im on 2005